# in SAS: create a JSON Web Signature for Google API

Tags: json, google-api, sas, java-web-start, jwt

I am using SAS 9.4.  I want to write a JSON Web Signature ("JWS") to complete my JSON Web Token ("JWT") - (I already have the header and claims encoded and tested).  I would like to make API calls to Google.  My problem is that I am not certain how to create the JWS.  Per all the docs and tutorial web sites I have researched the syntax to create the signature is (pseudo-code):

```
encodedContent = base64UrlEncode(header) + "." + base64UrlEncode(payload);
signature = hashHmacSHA256($encodedContent);
```

and/or

```
var encodedString = base64UrlEncode(header) + "." + base64UrlEncode(payload);
HMACSHA256(encodedString, 'secret');
```

etc.

I have been attempting to create the JWS using SAS PROC GROOVY code found here:
https://gist.github.com/FriedEgg/79ad315afa1b315e8ac3
...and other places.

Google's doc (https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) states:
"Sign the UTF-8 representation of the input ('{Base64url encoded header}.{Base64url encoded claim set}') using SHA256withRSA (also known as RSASSA-PKCS1-V1_5-SIGN with the SHA-256 hash function) with the private key obtained from the Google Developers Console. The output will be a byte array."

However, I am confused about what key to use (or whether I should be using a key) as some sites (example above) just suggest hashing the encoded header+claims while others suggest hashing using a "secret key" while say "private key" - and the github page (URL above) just uses a "key".

I am also confused about sha1 vs. sha256.  The Google docs sate sha256 but some have suggested sha1 in this Stack Overflow thread: questions/18362327/creating-digital-signature-usining-sas-for-google-api-geocode

Again, I have verified my header and claims SAS code work using:
**jwt dot io**
and
**kjur dot github dot io/jsjws /tool_jwt.html**

Since SAS supports Groovy (PROC GROOVY) I assume that I can write my JWT successfully using java code but I have not yet been able to replicate any JWT in my SAS code using examples found on the sites I have mentioned above and others.

Has anyone ever done this before (using SAS to connect to Google APIs using JWT)?

Any help is appreciated!